# Stop AppMaker deleting email address onSend

Tags: google-app-maker

Im just learning AppMaker and I have followed along the tutorial on sending email https://developers.google.com/appmaker/tutorials/call-scripts/

It works as expected so I decided to bring it to another level by integrating it into my sign up form.

**-- ISSUE OUTLINE --**

- A user enters their name and email in a standard signup form.
- This is saved as expected this data is presented on the follow up page I created (see screenshot below)
- When the admin clicks on the blue email button it opens up the email box (see attached image) and the users email is pulled into the To: box as expected (I have pulled the email by binding it to the text field).
- The admin then sends the email which is sent as expected but then the form clears the To: field deleting it from the users entry.

**-- QUESTION --**

- Can anyone advise on a solution it would be greatly appreciated :-)

**Screenshot:**
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the tutorial you mentioned, there is 'clearEmailForm' function that is called in case of successful sending email. I think you can delete code, that clears 'to' field:

```
/**
* Clears the entire email form
*/
function  clearEmailForm(){
  var formWidgets = app.pages.Email.descendants;
  ...
  formWidgets.To.value = ""; // Delete this line
  ...
}
```

Comment: Spot on Pavel thanks so much :-) thats working a treat.

Comment: Happy to help! Thank you for accepting the answer =)